# Windows 10 is resetting/not saving the default app settings for all file types and programs

Tags: windows, windows-10, file-association

I am using Windows 10, 64-bit, Version 1803, Build 17134.320.

When I try to set a new "Default App" for a certain file type or protocol (eg: .txt files) to be opened in, Windows does not save the setting and keeps resetting it to the system default.

I have tried multiple ways of applying the new settings:

1. Right click the file -> Properties -> Opens With -> Change
2. Right click the file -> Open With -> Choose another app -> Always use this app to open .txt files
3. PC Settings -> Apps -> Default Apps -> Choose default apps by file type/protocol

None are able to apply a new default app to a filetype.

When I try to change the association using option 3, the "SystemSettings.exe" application hangs for 5 seconds and then simply resets the options back to the system default.

I even contacted the Microsoft support and had two supporters remotely connected in order to fix the issue. Even they had no clue what causes it.

Comment: Does this happen if you boot only in Windows Safe mode?

Comment: I tried to do a system restore, now it works for me. I think there might be a bug in the latest windows update ? (I got it to work in 17134.285).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SSMS wont give up file associations](https://superuser.com/questions/1373310/ssms-wont-give-up-file-associations)