# SSMS wont give up file associations

Tags: windows-10, file-association, ssms

**Apparently this is a [known Win10 bug](https://www.digitaltrends.com/computing/new-windows-10-bug-messing-up-file-associations-2/) and should hopefully be fixed in an upcoming update.**

---

I have installed SQL Server Management Studio v17.9 on a clean Windows 10 installation.  This associated all `.sql` files with SSMS.

I want to associate `.sql` files with a plain text editor (eg: Sublime) but I am unable to change the default application.  I have tried:

- Right click `.sql` file -> Open With -> Sublime + "Always use this program".
- Settings -> Default Applications by File Type -> Find `.sql` -> Change to Sublime
- Right click `.sql` file -> Properties -> "Change" button -> Sublime.
- Using `ftype` via elevated command prompt as seen [here](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/How-to-associate-file-3898f323)

In all 3 cases, my selection is not reflected in any way, anywhere.  The icon remains SSMS, and the file opens with SSMS.

Is there some kind of "File Association retention" setting within SSMS I am unaware of?

Edit: I can change the default application for non-SSMS-associated extensions without issue.

Edit: after deleting registry key `HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.sql`, `.sql` files show a VSCode icon:

[image: No FileExts entry - VSCode Icon]

If I then double-click `New Users.sql`, it opens with SSMS and a refresh of regedit shows the `.sql` entry recreated with ssms.exe associated (the icon remains VSCode):

[image: Auto-created entry]

If I then right-click -> open with -> Choose Another App -> Select Sublime and hit "Always use this to open .sql files", it opens with Sublime and a refresh of regedit shows a new "b" entry created for Sublime.  The icon remains VSCode, and double-clicking opens it in SSMS:

[image: Sublime B-entry]

If I then delete the `a` entry for `ssms.exe` and rename `b` -> `a` such that only sublime exists, then double-click the .sql file, it opens with SSMS and generates a new `b` entry for itself:

[image: Manually removed ssms.exe]
[image: SSMS auto-entry]

Comment: What are the contents of the registry key `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.sql\OpenWithList`? Do they change when you associate the files with Sublime or are they somehow locked? If they seem locked, right-click the key, choose Permissions and add a screenshot. Note [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1271755/prevent-a-change-to-one-or-more-windows-10-registry-keys).

Comment: Deleting that key from registry, `.sql` files show VSCode icon.  Double-clicking file opens it in SSMS and creates new `.sql` registry entry with `ssms.exe`.  Open with -> anything adds new key "b", "c" etc in the OpenWithList.

Comment: If you are running Windows 10 1803 or 1809 this is a known confirmed bug.  It’s also going to be fixed by the end of November.  There really isn’t a work around at this time.  All you can do is wait for the cumulative patch that fixes it.

Comment: @Ramhound yeah I'm running 1803.  Do you have any links you could share in an answer for me to accept?

Comment: @AlexMcMillan - You want a link that confirms this is a bug?

Comment: @AlexMcMillan There are about 12 duplicates here at SuperUser.  Granted all with commentary from myself indicating it’s a bug.

Comment: @xakepp35 - Sounds like a perfect reason to submit your own question since you are running Windows 7.  Microsoft has not been hacked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I have installed SQL Server Management Studio v17.9 on a clean Windows 10 installation. This associated all .sql files with SSMS.  I want to associate .sql files with a plain text editor (eg: Sublime) but I am unable to change the default application.

If you are running Windows 10 1803 or 1809 this is a known confirmed bug.  The bug first appeared on PCs running **Windows 10 April 2018 Update Build 17134.320** (KB4458469) which was issued on October 9.  It also appears on PCs running **Windows 10 October 2018 Update Build 17763.55 (KB4464330)** which was also issued on October 9th, 2018.

For those machines running the April 2018 Update, Microsoft issued a patch [KB4467682](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4467682), in order to address this issue on November 27th, 2018.  For those machines running the October 2018 Update, Microsoft issued a patch [KB4469342](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4469342/november292018kb4469342osbuild17763167), in order to address this issue on December 5th, 2018.

> Addresses an issue that prevents some users from setting Win32 program defaults for certain app and file type combinations using the **Open with…** command or **Settings > Apps > Default apps**.

[Source](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4467682)

Comment: This information took my thinking in a completely different direction; thanks.

Comment: This likely will be resolved with a build equal or greater to 17763.165+ for the October 2018 Update (1809) based on an analysis of when 17134.441 was built compared to when it was released (about 10 days).

Comment: Is there anything I can do right now if my Windows Update decides it's fully updated, KB4469342 decides it's "not applicable" to my computer and KB4467682 isn't in the update catalog for download?

Comment: 17134.441 was pulled earlier this week.  You will have to wait until the next cumulative update is released.  KB4469342 is also applicable if you running Windows 10 October 2018 Update (1809), but you are running Windows 10 April 2018 Update (1803), so you will have to wait until the next 1803 cumulative update is released