# I can't change any extension's default application

Tags: windows, windows-10

After i was forced to shutdown my pc forcefully with the button, my **js files** became without a **default app**, when i click on a js file the **dialog box** didn't have the checkbox **'always use...'** anymore, when i tried to set an app manually from the file properties **'Open with'** it didn't change it keep being **unknown application**.

This problem isn't only with **js extension** i can't change any **extension's default app**.

Edit: I can't change it from **default apps sittings** either, when i choose notepad++ or other programs, it set it automatically to "Microsoft windows based script host" the only program that get accepted otherwise is visual studio

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SSMS wont give up file associations](https://superuser.com/questions/1373310/ssms-wont-give-up-file-associations)

Comment: Try to do it from "Default programs".

Comment: It didn't work either, when i choose notepad++ or other programs it set it automatically to "Microsoft windows based script host" the only program that get accepted otherwise is visual studio?

Answer (score 1):

You need then to do it the hard way:

- Open regedit
- Navigate to the key `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\JSFile\Shell\Open\Command`
- Double-click the `(Default)` item
- Save its current value as backup
- Enter the new value `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\notepad++.exe" "%1"`
- And the deed is done.

You may also use the following `.reg` file:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\JSFile\Shell\Open\Command]
@="\"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Notepad++\\notepad++.exe\" \"%1\""
```

Comment: Thank you for your idea but it didn't work

Comment: It worked for me. I wonder what's different on your side.

Comment: Yeah its really strange, well i will just wait for the problem to solve itself with some windows updates or program installation, thanks for your help man.