# Problems authorizing Ableton Live 10

Tags: windows-10, firefox, authorization, ableton-live

**Necessary description**

I have recently bought Ableton Live, and I installed it as suggested, but: when I press on the "authorize with ableton.com" button, it takes me to my account, but I just see a download for Ableton Live 10 (Standard), I have already downloaded it after buying it.
I installed Firefox, but there is no way at all, to make it the default browser. There is something off with Windows... Firefox does not show up in the default browsers.

I went ahead with the offline activation using the .auz file, but Windows needs to set a default program to open it, but after browsing my PC and choosing ableton as a default, it does not open and then it drops the same message, something like: Windows needs to have a default program to open that. I opened the file from LIVE like a new set live, but Live said the file was damaged.

I tried again with the online authorization using Internet explorer and Edge, which are the only programs that I can set as default browsers appart from Chrome, I saw a screen that said it was connecting to LIVE but after a while, it said: time out, try again.

I have tried almost everything except formating my PC and downloading Ableton Live again, I have re-installed Live three times, I re-installed Firefox two times, and I have followed everything, and there seems to be no way to authorize Live. With export and saving deactivated Ableton works fine, but I can't authorize it.

Any help is much appreciated

**Aditional information:**

Recently my PC ran into automatic recovery after it failed booting during a Windows actualization, I took the desktop to technical support and they restored it without formating it, they just inserted a USB into my PC that contained Windows, so windows could find there the missing files and repaired itself.
I will include the OS information in case it helps:

*Edition: Windows 10 Pro*

*Version: 1803*

*Operative System version: 17134.472.*

*System tipe: 64-bit operating system, x64-based processor*

Comment: We are always glad to help, but can you please edit your question to include the appropriate [Windows 10 version and OS build number](https://www.howtogeek.com/236195/how-to-find-out-which-build-and-version-of-windows-10-you-have/) that you are currently using?  Within certain versions of Windows 10, there is a [known issue](https://superuser.com/a/1374236/650163) that breaks the capability to change system default applications.  An appropriate update may help you in that regard.

Comment: @Run5k Thank you! Can you please check the question again to see if I included what you asked for?
And again, thank you very much!

Comment: Thanks for the quick feedback, but that isn't quite right.  Please read the article that I hyperlinked in my previous comment that shows how to determine your Windows 10 version and OS build number.

Comment: Okay, I think I have corrected the issue, let me know if it works. Thanks!

Comment: @Run5k Hi! Did you see my edit? Let me know if it's okay to update windows to solve the problem. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, I was actually driving to work.  Occasionally, real life interferes with Super User!  ;-)  That being said, your OS version already has the patch that I mentioned within the "known issue" hyperlink, so that isn't the root cause of the problem.  Hopefully, someone else can chime in who has encountered this issue before.

Comment: Hmmmm...
Weird, I will update windows to see if the problem persists